# Laravel 4.2 Model Events don't fire on ajax

Tags: php, laravel

I have this on my  model

```
public static function boot()
{
    // there is some logic in this method, so don't forget this!
    parent::boot();

    Deal::created(function ($deal) {
        // or something
        $merchant = Deal::find($deal->deal_id)->merchant;
        $activity = new Activity;
        $activity->doer_id = $merchant->merchant_id;
        $activity->doer_name = $merchant->merchant_name;
        $activity->event_type= $merchant->merchant_name. " posted ".$deal->deal_name;
        $activity->save();


    });

    Deal::updated(function ($deal) {

                                    $merchant = Deal::find($deal->deal_id)->merchant;
                                $activity = new Activity;
                                $activity->doer_id = $merchant->merchant_id;
                                $activity->doer_name = $merchant->merchant_name;
                                if($$deal->deal_status == 1){
                                    $activity->event_type= $deal->deal_name. " was approved ";
                                }else{
                                    $activity->event_type= $deal->deal_name. " was rejected ";
                                }

                                $activity->save();


    });
}
```

normal post process it saves on my activity table but when i do ajax call i wont and it does not have errors . please help me out on this

Comment: Are you sure the model is being created or updated when doing the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Anytime I need to use ajax in Laravel, I write an app-dependent API for using Ajax. Truthfully, Laravel uses an MVC style architecture, and following those guidelines, only a controller should interact with a model. My suggestion would be to write a route that the ajax call makes a request to, and use that controller method tied to the route to handle the ajax call, and save information to the DB with your model.